# reading a specific column in log file using python and make csv file

Tags: python, csv, logfile

I am trying to read an log file which contains the following texts  and want to convert to .csv file, but not comes as in proper format,
for example,

```
UNIT_TYPE   BUS_TYPE      GEN          TIME   GROUP     QoS    PURPOSE   INFO    BUY-ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
web        VOLVO    cc/CUSTOM[10]   14:30:48   MAJ      CHKD      TOBE GENERAL PUBLIC.                    2          
web         VOLVO   cc/CUSTOM[10]    12:20:08   MAJ      CHKD      TOBE GENERAL PUBLIC.                    2          
DIR         VOLVO   cc/CUSTOM[10]   11:31:48   MAJ      CHKD      TOBE GENERAL PUBLIC.                    2                    
DIR         HYNDAI  cc/CUSTOM[10]   10:10:48   MAJ      CHKD      TOBE GENERAL PUBLIC.                    2
```

> 111.222.333.123 HOME - [01/Feb/1998:01:08:39 -0800] "ad.htm HTTP/1.0" 200 198 "ba_intro.htm" "Mozilla/4.01 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"
>
> 111.222.333.123 HOME - [01/Feb/1998:01:08:46 -0800] "ad.htm HTTP/1.0" 200 28083 "bannerad/ba_intro.htm" "Mozilla/4.01 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"
>
> 111.222.333.123 AWAY - [01/Feb/1998:01:08:53 -0800] "ad7.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 9332 "bannerad/ba_ad.htm" "Mozilla/4.01 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"
>   [/code]

I need to write each column with its heading in csv file format.,
like `[unit type,web,web,web,web]`, `[bus type,volvo,volvo,volvo,volvo]`.

after below the table,
also, want to extract the HOME,away and ip addresses such as `[HOME,01/Feb/1998, 08:39]`, `[AWAY,01/Feb/1998,01:08:53]`.

In python, csv also not able to convert proper csv file..
How can I properly convert as CSV format?
Any examples or guide could help.

Comment: You want to achieve the first and get the second out of your `log`-file?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want to do, and especially what your (missing) Python code is doing that is a problem.

Comment: Hi,
 [code]inF = csv.reader(open('log.txt, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
outF = csv.writer(open('out.csv, 'wb'))
writer = csv.writer(outF, delimiter=",")
           for row in list_results:
                        writer.writerow(columns)        [code] 

 Here, I want to get each column of the log file into csv format in excel sheet...i.e. each row and column in separate column in excel sheet  ... but all values printed in a same shell in excel sheet... how can I do this... thank you